# Unable to use package across files

Tags: go

I am still learning Go, and I am stuck at this issue where I cannot use the `struct` I created in the `main` package

> app.go

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "database/sql"

// struct named App to hold our application
type App struct {
    Router *mux.Router
    DB     *sql.DB
}
```

> main_test.go

```golang
package main_test 

import (
    "testing"
    "log"
    "os"
)

// application we want to test 
var a main.App //  throws error
```

When I run the test `go test -v`, it throws the following error:

```
# pg_mux_test [pg_mux.test]
.\main_test.go:10:7: undefined: main 
FAIL    pg_mux [build failed]
```

Comment: Both of these files are in the different package?

Comment: Import the package to reference identifiers in the package.   Add main's import path to the list of imports in main_test.go.

Comment: my module's name is `pg_mux` and I tried importing as `pg_mux/main`. It's giving me this error now: `main_test.go:7:2: package pg_mux/main is not in GOROOT`

Comment: If your go.mod file is in the same directory as main.go, then import `"pg_mux"`.  An import specifies the package path.

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: I may not be giving a precise answer since it's not clear about your project structure, still making an attempt since I was at first very confused with imports in Go.  And this is answer is valid only if you are using go packages (with go mod init stuff).*

As an example, say your go.mod package name is `main` and your folder structure is something like:

```
.
├── app.go
├── go.mod
└── someDirName // (say main_test)
    └── main_test.go
```

Then, you can import `main` package in your `main_test.go` as follows:

```golang
package main_test 

import (
    // ... other imports
    "main" //  import it here
)

// application we want to test 
var a main.App //  this time, it wont' throw error
```